# Javascript Slider using Wordpress Loop

Tags: javascript, wordpress, slider

I am having issues with a slider I have on a wordpress site.  [www.towntalkradio.com](http://www.towntalkradio.com)

1)  The back button is not functioning

2)  The code is supposed to call a count of all of the posts in the specified category and display all of those posts.  The count is not working correctly and only part of the posts are being displayed (ex. 7 when there are 19 in the category)

I inherited this code and I have very limited experience with this setup.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I apologize if I did not submit this correctly, I am new here.

[Javascript](http://codepad.org/up02bNud)
[Index.php](http://codepad.org/JchmyBGe)

Answer (score 0):

The value you are getting is the posts per page setting. 
(Settings > Reading > Blog pages show at most)

give this a go on line 9:

`<?php query_posts('cat=4&order=DESC&posts_per_page=-1');?>`

be sure to use `wp_reset_query()` after your loop.

`query_posts` is meant for altering the main loop, `WP_Query` or `get_post`
might be better options when running multiple loops.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query